# How to make a string as an optional to wait for it in an expect script?

Tags: linux, bash, expect

The below script works in the case, where all three questions are being asked, but sometimes the `Do you trust the above certificate [y|N] -->` question is not asked by `asadmin ...` and so my `expect` fails.

**Question**

Is it possible to make the `Do you trust the above certificate [y|N] -->` question optional, so the `expect` script doesn't fails when this question in not asked?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set password [lindex $argv 0]

spawn asadmin --user admin change-admin-password
expect "password"
send "\n"
expect "password"
send "$password\n"
expect "password"
send "$password\n"
expect "Do you trust the above certificate \[y\|N\] -->"
send "y\n"
expect eof
exit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set password [lindex $argv 0]

spawn asadmin --user admin change-admin-password

 # First time, when we see the password, we are simply typing 'return' key
expect "password"
send "\n"

expect { 
        "password"  { send "$password\n"; exp_continue }
        -ex "Do you trust the above certificate \[y|N] -->" {send "y\n";exp_continue}
        timeout { puts "Timeout happened." } 
        eof { exit }
 }
```

As you can see, `exp_continue` will help us in getting what you need.

If `expect` sees `password`, it will send the password value. Notice the use of `exp_continue` in there.
It will cause the expect to run again. So, the `expect` will see the password twice and if suppose, `expect` sees the question, it will send `'y\n'`. If it sees `eof` before, then script will exit.

Please note that I have kept the first `expect` statement with password separately outside. The reason being is nothing but the value we are sending is different for the first time alone.

Also note the use of the `-ex` flag in the expect statement as below.

```
-ex "Do you trust the above certificate \[y|N] -->" {send "y\n";exp_continue}
```

It will make the expect to prevent any sort of special pattern matching. It is sufficient to escape the first square bracket alone.